ASWebAuthenticationSession doesn't load iframe
Intro
I want to integrate a proprietary token provider into the WatchOS app. Communication with this provider happens with custom js SDK.
So generally I have a plan to write my own HTML page to get the token in javascript and then deliver it to native code with window.location.href = "myapp_scheme://?token=" + token;
Problem
Under the hood this proprietary JS SDK creates iframe and it looks like ASWebAuthenticationSession doesn't allow to load iframe.
Here is a simple example below reproduces the problem:
ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.webAuthenticationSession) private var webAuthenticationSession

    @State private var token: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(token ?? "No Token")
            Button("Get Token") {
                Task {
                    do {
                        let urlWithToken = try await webAuthenticationSession.authenticate(
                            using: URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/token-webos-demo.html")!,
                            callbackURLScheme: "token-callback-url"
                        )

                        let queryItems = URLComponents(string: urlWithToken.absoluteString)?.queryItems

                        token = queryItems?.filter({ $0.name == "token" }).first?.value
                    } catch {
                        // Respond to any authorization errors.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

token-webos-demo.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Token Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="https://example.com" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>

This is how the same html looks in MacOS'/iOS's Safari

And watchOS


Questions
I didn't manage to find any information about iframe restriction in ASWebAuthenticationSession docs, maybe there is another problem with why iframe isn't requested?
